# WPF Animation Does Not Play At Runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, designer

I have a progress indicator that is running perfectly in the designer, but fails to move an inch when debugged. The same code (besides the namespaces of course) works fine for another one of my projects, but I cannot replicate the feat onto any other besides that one. As it stands, the animation is running, as the dots "blink" (the resetting of their position for the animation), but they do not move like they should and do in the designer.

Here is an image of what is should look like: http://oi62.tinypic.com/2u5ukvm.jpg

Here is an image of what it currently looks like: http://oi58.tinypic.com/2n6g9rl.jpg

ProgressIndicator.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Iris.UI.ProgressIndicator"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:UI="clr-namespace:Iris.UI"
             x:Name="progressIndicator"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <UI:WidthPercentageConverter x:Key="WidthPercentageConverter" />
        <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseIn" x:Key="ProgressBarEaseIn"/>

        <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseIn" x:Key="ProgressBarEaseOut" />

        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="00:00:04.4" x:Key="animate">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="R1TT">
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=.32}" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ProgressBarEaseOut}" />
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=.65}" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ProgressBarEaseIn}" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="R2TT">
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=.32}" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ProgressBarEaseOut}" />
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=.65}" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ProgressBarEaseIn}" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="R3TT">
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=.32}" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ProgressBarEaseOut}" />
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=.65}" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ProgressBarEaseIn}" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="R4TT">
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=.32}" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ProgressBarEaseOut}" />
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=.65}" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ProgressBarEaseIn}" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="R5TT">
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=.32}" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ProgressBarEaseOut}" />
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=.65}" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthPercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ProgressBarEaseIn}" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="R1">
                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="R2">
                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="R3">
                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="R4">
                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="R5">
                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource animate}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
    <Border x:Name="IndeterminateRoot" Visibility="Visible"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource MetroStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="False" Width="4" x:Name="R1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="R1TT" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource MetroStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="False" Width="4" x:Name="R2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="R2TT" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource MetroStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="False" Width="4" x:Name="R3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="R3TT" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource MetroStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="False" Width="4" x:Name="R4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="R4TT" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource MetroStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="False" Width="4" x:Name="R5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="R5TT" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

ProgressIndicator.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace Iris.UI
{
    public class WidthPercentageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var percentage = Double.Parse(parameter.ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-US"));
            return ((double)value) * percentage;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public partial class ProgressIndicator
    {
        public ProgressIndicator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            IsVisibleChanged += (s, e) => ((ProgressIndicator)s).StartStopAnimation();
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(VisibilityProperty, GetType());
            dpd.AddValueChanged(this, (s, e) => ((ProgressIndicator)s).StartStopAnimation());
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ProgressColourProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ProgressColour", typeof(Brush), typeof(ProgressIndicator), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public Brush ProgressColour
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(ProgressColourProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ProgressColourProperty, value); }
        }

        private void StartStopAnimation()
        {
            bool shouldAnimate = (Visibility == Visibility.Visible && IsVisible);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                var s = Resources["animate"] as Storyboard;
                if (s != null)
                {
                    if (shouldAnimate)
                        s.Begin();
                    else
                        s.Stop();
                }
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add XAML and code. Do not expect people to follow external links.

Comment: It'd make the question body far too long. Not to mention those are proven reputable sites.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  As Clemens mentioned, linking to code externally is frowned upon.  You're also encouraged to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to ask questions that are more appropriate for this site.

Comment: It's now in the question.

Comment: Is the s.Begin() code entered correctly?

Comment: Yes, it does reach that part of the code.